# How to display cells of UICollectionView from right to left instead of left to right?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

This is what I have now (*by default*):

[image]

but I would like to have:

[image]

I display it using `NSFetcheResultsController` with descending order for my property.

Comment: Hello @BartłomiejSemańczyk . I figured out even more simpler way to do it, I would like to share it with you, hope it helps :)

Answer (score 7):

**The simplest way** to achieve it is to change the value of the collection view [`semanticContentAttribute`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622461-semanticcontentattribute) enumeration instance property:

> A semantic description of the view’s contents, used to determine
>   whether the view should be flipped when switching between
>   left-to-right and right-to-left layouts.

by setting to `.forceRightToLeft`, as follows:

```
// 'viewDidLoad' would be a proper method to do it:
override func viewDidLoad() {
    // ...

    collectionView.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same problem, after searching for any possible built-in feature that let me able to do this easily, -unfortunately- I couldn't find such a thing. I had to solve it by my self by doing this trick:

*For the purpose of demonstration, I will present this  -ugly- collectionView and show you how it should changes:*

[image]

The main idea of the trick is **Mirroring!** by changing the scaleX to -1.

Let's mirror the whole collection view:

*P.S: Swift 3 code.*

If you don't have an IBOutlet for your collectionView, create one. In my case im calling it `collectionView`

In viewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    collectionView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: 1)
}
```

Now, it should look like this:

[image]

**"What the heck?!"**

So far so good, in fact this is exactly what you are looking for, but you still need to add another mirroiring mechanism for each cell content.

In your custom cell's class:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    contentView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: 1)
}
```

Now it should look like this:

[image]

Hope it helped.

Comment: that's right it's not an elegant way, but at least as workaround it works! as I mentioned, I couldn't find a better way to do it...

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to subclass `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and implement it like this:

```
class CustomFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    //MARK: - Private

    private func reversedRect(for rect: CGRect) -> CGRect {

        let point = reversedPoint(for: rect.origin)
        let newPoint = CGPoint(x: point.x - rect.size.width, y: point.y)

        return CGRect(x: newPoint.x, y: newPoint.y, width: rect.size.width, height: rect.size.height)
    }

    private func reversedPoint(for point: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
        return CGPoint(x: collectionViewContentSize.width - point.x, y: point.y)
    }

    //MARK: - Overridden

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {

        guard let attributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: reversedRect(for: rect)) else {
            return nil
        }

        for attribute in attributes {
            attribute.center = reversedPoint(for: attribute.center)
        }

        return attributes
    }
}
```

Simply assign it in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0):

```
class RTLCollectionViewFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    override var flipsHorizontallyInOppositeLayoutDirection: Bool {
        return true
    }

    override var developmentLayoutDirection: UIUserInterfaceLayoutDirection {
        return UIUserInterfaceLayoutDirection.rightToLeft
    }
}
```